# Play framework: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, playframework

I am trying to upload same files to Amazon S3 using play framework, but every time I get this exception:
**The difference between the request time and the current time is too large**

I changed the computer time-zone but I got the same exception. Next, I ran my play-application using 
**./activator -Duser.timezone=PST "run 9000"**

But all time I got the same exception. Is there any one who meet this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: set your local time to auto-sync with network

Comment: My local time is auto-sync